# Ruby: Prime number list with just one number output

Tags: ruby, primes

I have a problem in simple task, however can't figure it out for hours and also can't find any examples.

Thing I want to make - Ruby generates list of prime numbers, user enters a number (for example - 5), Ruby shows that 5th prime number is 11.

I have a code for prime number generation -

```
def isPrime(n)
    for i in 2...n
       return false if (n%i) == 0
    end
end

(2..1000).each { |x| puts x if isPrime(x) }
```

Comment: Have you been through any Ruby tutorials on reading user input? Converting input to a number? There should be many examples of that online. Then you just need to loop through the prime number generator using the user input as a counter of successes.

Comment: Yes. I am now studying Ruby in the first year of university. Have made some complicated tasks, just got stuck with this one. Seems that there are some holes in my Ruby comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should save your prime numbers to an array:

```
@primes = []
(2..1000).each do |x|
  @primes << x if isPrime(x)
end
```

Or a bit shorter using [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
@primes = (2..1000).select { |x| isPrime(x) }
```

Now you can process user input:

```
loop do
  print "enter a number: "
  n = gets.to_i
  puts @primes.fetch(n-1) { "unknown prime" }
end
```

[`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) reads one line from STDIN, [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) converts the input to an integer (ignoring the newline at the end) and [`Array#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch) fetches the prime at index `n-1` from the array or returns a message for unknown primes (outside the array).

BTW, you should use `snake_case` for method names:

```
def is_prime(n)
  # ...
end
```

and preferably use `?` for predicate methods:

```
def prime?(n)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gets` to take input from the command line.

Also, Ruby has a `Prime` library you may find useful:

```
require 'prime'

puts "Which prime?"
x = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "Prime ##{x} is: #{Prime.first(x).last}"
```

Running:

```
$ ruby prime.rb 
Which prime?
5
Prime #5 is: 11
```

Comment: Thanks!

yeah, as I thought, it is really easy. 

However, how can I make this without using library, as I want to digest the working principe. Is my generator worth anything?

Comment: It's close, it will print every prime from 2..1000 regardless of input.  You'll need to keep a counter every time you find a prime, and only print when that counter is whatever value is inputted.  Also, you may need a much larger range, since I can input a large number that won't be in 2..1000.  Consider just using a counter for that as well, so it can grow without a limit.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `gets` , you might want to add some kind of counter reach your solution.

For example, if the user wanted the fifth prime number, you would have the counter start at 0. and after each time the method is ran, the counter moves up +1 until you reached five.

```
counter=0
counter+=1
until counter =userinput
```